# How can i Configure aws cli profile with Elastic Beanstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am using Elastic Beanstack for deploying my application. During deploying I have to run some command. So I have prepare `.ebextensions` script for it. which my script does

1. python (`pip`)
2. aws cli
3. and some `aws` command which i need to configure the aws profile (`aws configure`)

So how can I configure the `aws profile` with Elastic Beanstack in batch script in `.ebextensions`.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk uses a different program for the command line interface.

To install awsebcli for Linux:

pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user

For Windows:

[Install Python, pip, and the EB CLI on Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html?shortFooter=true)

Comment: Sorry, I am using batch script with `.ebextension`. i need `aws configure` and put the configuration on it in batch script